# Lge or Lrg as an abbreviation for "Large"?

Tags: abbreviations

I have an application which has not enough horizontal space, so I want to make some words shorter.

A drop-down list has the options Small, Medium, and Large.

I'm thinking of changing it to this:

- Sml
- Med
- Lge

Is this the best choice of abbreviations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, personally, I wouldn't realize what "Lge" was without context, while I would understand "Lrg" without context. Because this is a drop-down menu, I would understand both, but "Lrg" would be better.

The most common forms of abbreviation are:

- Omitting vowels/double letters (e.g. "Large" to "Lrg" or "Small" to "Sml")
- Initializing (e.g. "Large" to "L" or "Small" to "S")
- Abbreviating to n characters (e.g. "Large" to "Lar" or "Small" to "Sma")

Anything that doesn't conform to these styles will probably be less understandable at a glance, and the first two styles are especially common for "small" and "large"